# Python MySQL-Connector failing to connect intermittently on Windows VPS

Tags: python, mysql, linux, server, mysql-connector

I am scraping data using a Windows VPS. I am using Python MySQL-Connector to upload this scraped data to a Linux dedicated server.

```
import mysql.connector

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="...",
      user="...",
      password="...",
      database="...",
      connection_timeout=60
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

About 25% of the time this fails, or takes more than twenty seconds. When it fails I get a 10060 error. Is the problem more likely to be with my Linux server or more likely my Windows VPS? Help sincerely appreciated. Here is the error message:

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '[IP]:3306', system error: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Are you inserting data larger than the `max_allowed_packet` setting? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am not sure. I have logs of the records that where supposed to be inserted. When I insert them by running the Python script on my local machine. It works fine. What do you think that could mean? Thanks for pointing out that resource. Reading now.

Comment: If you're using "localhost" to connect to your local machine, the max_allowed_packet may not be enforced, because you're not even using TCP to connect. Localhost uses the UNIX domain socket instead. I wonder if your app would work locally if you connect via "127.0.0.1", forcing it to use a TCP connection?

Comment: When I said "local machine" I meant my laptop. So when I upload through the script (using remote MySQL) it fails 2% of the time. When I execute the same quires using the same script on my laptop it seems to always work fine.

Comment: This bloke seems to be facing the same exact problem.https://johnnn.tech/q/intermittent-mysql-lost-connection-system-error-10060/. Not how he is suspecting that "Maybe the problem is related to the fact that I have shared hosting and have not paid for a private server."

Comment: How much data (in MB) are you sending to the server?

Comment: Could you post from failing MySQL server TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeo%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%timeo%'; and C) STATUS: - not SHOW STATUS and D) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime%';  and E) LAST 400 lines of your error log.  There may be clues.

Comment: vi my.cnf\
bind-address=0.0.0.0\
skip-name-resolve=1

restart mysql

Comment: Please also POST TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'aborted%': for analysis.  Happy New Year!

Comment: using wire shark, we can try and weed out network issue, run wireshark to capture the network traffic between the two server on port 3306. when it crashes, check if it's due to no response from the server or because the port closed and the call kept retrying untill it ran out of time.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely ralated to slow mysql database server, so you could do following:

1. Increase your `connection_timeout` to higher value i.e. 600.
2. Configure settings that are responsible for database server perormance (i.e. see this presentation - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-day/mysql-performance-tuning-403029.pdf) especially set mysql RAM usage server (1/2 of total system RAM - variable innodb_buffer_pool_size (set it in my.cnf))
3. Ensure that your closes cursor ***after your finished to use it***, call `mycursor.close`.
4. Increase if possible resources (CPU, RAM, more faster disk drive) of a system with your database server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, I suspect this is caused by a port being blocked (the default TCP/IP port of the MySQL server is 3306).

Check if the port 3306 is busy:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 3306
```

then try to free that port before running your app again.

Comment: if its failing only 25% of the time, then the port is open.